# Setting HttpClientHander.set_AutomaticDecompression with FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, restsharp

I have the following method which when run causes a MissingMethodException Method ('System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression' not found)

```
    public async Task<TokenResponseModel> Login (string username, string password)
    {
       var tokenResponse = new TokenResponseModel ();
        try {
            var request = new RestRequest (Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter ("username", username);
            request.AddParameter ("password", password);
            request.AddParameter ("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
            using (var client = new RestClient (GetStringRequest ("Token"))) {
                var json = await client.Execute<TokenResponseModel> (request);
                tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponseModel> (json.Content);
            }
            return tokenResponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.WriteLine ("Exception thrown - {0}--{1}", e.Message, e.InnerException);
            return tokenResponse;
        }
    }
```

I know I can set the AutomaticDecompression with a ClientHandler, but I can seem to find a way to connect the ClientHandler to the RestClient. Is there a way that I can directly connect the ClientHandler to RestClient or can RestSharp.Portable set the AutomaticDecompression by itself?

Comment: Did you get this to work?